# Transform the shape and colors of legend in scatterplot in base R

Tags: r, plot, colors, legend

I am trying to make this scatterplot in base R:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdgGN.png

This scatterplot is based on the *mtcars* data.

Now I tried this, however I cannot get the same legend.
How can I transform the squares into dots?
How do I get the exact same colors?
How do I know which format the legend is?

This is my code:

```
cols = c("deepskyblue", "magenta", "gray50")
plot(mpg ~ wt, xlab="Weight (1000lbs)", ylab="Miles / gallon", col = cyl, pch = 19, data=mtcars)
legend(x = "topright",
       title = "Number of cylinders",
       horiz = TRUE,
       legend = c("4", "6", "8"), 
       bty = 'n',
       cex = 0.7,
       fill = cols)
```

By the way: I made *cols* for now, but I think there is another way to solve it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

"Fill" means that squares with be filled by a colour.
What you need is to use the "pch" argument **instead**, so you can add the "col" argument to chose for your dots colors.
For info, pch corresponds to the shape you want to chose in your legend.
*https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/06/r-plot-pch-symbols-different-point-shapes-in-r/*

Replace

`fill=cols`

by

```
col = cols,
pch=19)
```

Full code:

```
cols = c("deepskyblue", "magenta", "gray50")
plot(mpg ~ wt, xlab="Weight (1000lbs)", ylab="Miles / gallon", col = cyl, pch = 19, data=mtcars)
legend(x = "topright",
       title = "Number of cylinders",
       horiz = TRUE,
       legend = c("4", "6", "8"), 
       bty = 'n',
       cex = 0.7,
       col = cols,
       pch=19)
```

If you want to use different colors, then you can chose among the following ones.
[http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~tzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Etzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf)